# BlackBerry Momentics can't find SDK

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

We installed Momentics IDE here on folder `/opt/bbndk` using sudo and set all files and folders permissions to 777 (so all user would be able to run it). But when we run it using another user, it shows this error below:

[image: error]

If I run it with sudo, it runs normally. I don't see what's going on here, if all files are accessible to all users, it should be able to read the SDK as well.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [another possible solution](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/quot-No-SDK-can-be-found-quot-error-on-Linux-installation/td-p/2066063) (but did not work on my computer),here is my solution:
(1) Download the latest NDK from BB website 
(2) Change the .bin file to be executable (*chmod +x YourDownloadedNDK.bin*) 
(3) Install .bin file directly (*./YourDownloadedNDK.bin*). Do NOT use "sudo" (OR it will kick a part of the NDK to the root and then it won't work. I am not sure why.) 
(4) Note: when the installer ask for "location", directly input the desired path (hit "choose location" button froze the installer on my computer) 
(5) After installation is done, the QNX Momentics should be in the good shape.